# Unable to connect to inernet in an Ubuntu 14.04 VM installed over windows 7 guest os

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I've created a Ubuntu 14.04 VM using oracle's VirtualBox on my Windows 7 PC. I've also managed to install drivers form Guest Additions CD image, but in spite of all that I still can't get the internet to work on this VM.

I've tried restarting the network drivers but to no avail. Please understand that I'm new to Linux so I'm not familiar with a lot of other troubleshooting procedures. Any ideas are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: how have you configure the network card in virtualbox there about 4 options some are internal some are external

Comment: I tried using everything from DHCP, DHCP (addresses only), link-local only but none of them seems to work. There's only one nic i.e. eth0 and for some reason I can't edit the contents. I keep getting a permission denied error.

Comment: there's only one adapter and it is set as NAT.

Comment: NAT is the correct way so the will be issue in the virtual machine do you know how to open terminal?

Comment: Yes, I can do all the basic stuff. Also, I tried to ping my host from the vm but the host was unreachable. I can also see that my host IP is in 10.241.32.** range whereas the VM has 169.254.7.*** range.

Comment: do sudo ifconfig -a and ping the ip address of your router to

Comment: sudo ipconfig -a gave the following result: eth0      Link 
                 RX packets:112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:54 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11435 (11.4 KB)  TX bytes:8552 (8.5 KB)

Comment: Adding to what I just said, I can ping the vm from host but not the vice versa

Comment: you done sudo ipconfig -a? if so you need to do sudo ifconfig -a ipconfig is fo windows

Comment: Sorry I made a typo there. anyway, I executed "sudo ifconfig -a" but that provided me with eth0 information. I tried to set static ip to my vm and now I'm able to ping it from the host but still cant access the internet

Comment: try sudo ifup eth0

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @abalter: This was long time ago so I don't remember the exact details but yes I did get it to work playing around with the inet adapter.